# Maven error: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read local copy of metadata

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I was trying to compile my Java Maven project. I compiled it successfully a min ago and suddenly these errors started showing up:

> Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read local copy of metadata: Cannot read metadata from maven metadata tinkerpop repository.xml

I tried to go step by step and made sure that the end tag is the same as the end tag and then I got this error and I am stuck:

I am using Apache Maven 2.2.1, Java version: 1.7.

Comment: Stop using Maven 2.X (Long end of life) use Maven 3+

Comment: Does it work with Java 1.7?